# Особенности использования условий в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, условия

Есть `DataFrame`, в котором надо заполнить `col3` данными из `col2` по условию:

```
mask = ((df['col3'].isnull()) & (df['col1'] == 2))
```

```py
 col1   col2    col3
0   2   2   NaN
1   3   1   NaN
2   2   1   NaN
3   3   1   NaN
4   2   2   NaN
```

Вывожу данные, которые должны быть изменены в `col3`:

```py
mask = ((df['col3'].isnull()) & (df['col1'] == 2))
df.loc[mask]

 col1   col2 col3
0   2   2   NaN
2   2   1   NaN
4   2   2   NaN
```

Выполняю заполнение:

```py
df.loc[mask, 'col3'] = df['col2']
df
```

Проверяю результат:

```py
df
 col1   col2 col3
0   2   2   2.0
1   3   1   NaN
2   2   1   1.0
3   3   1   NaN
4   2   2   2.0
```

Все ОК, но на большом объеме данных так не проверишь.

Повторно использую для этого маску:

```py
df.loc[mask]

 col1 col2  col3
0   2   2   2.0
2   2   1   1.0
4   2   2   2.0
```

Ожидал, что будет пустой список, т.к. `col3` заполнена данными, а в маске существует условие `df['col3'].isnull()` - выводить только незаполненные.

Почему так произошло и в чем я ошибся?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логическая ошибка в том, что переменная `mask` была создана **до** заполнения `col3`.

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     2     2   2.0
1     3     1   NaN
2     2     1   1.0
3     3     1   NaN
4     2     2   2.0
```

Создаем логическую маску после обновления:

```
In [13]: mask = ((df['col3'].isna()) & (df['col1'] == 2))
```

и получаем пустой DataFrame:

```
In [14]: df.loc[mask]
Out[14]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
Index: []
```

PS методы `.isnull()` / `.notnull()` являются устаревшими, лучше использовать `.isna()` / `.notna()`.

Comment: Так и хочется сказать - "Семен Семеныч ...."
Большое спасибо @MaxU и @0xdb!!!

Comment: Кстати, оказалось очень удобно проверять результат таким способом...